# Fibonacci that takes a list of numbers and returns their fibonacci number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to implement a function that will print a number of fibonacci numbers. For example if my input was fibonacci([0,1,2,3], the output would be 0,1,1,2.

I am not sure how to proceed.

```
def fibonacci(n):

    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n-2)

    while True:
        n.append(n)

print(fibonacci[5,10,11])
```

Comment: what should be your output for `fibonacci[5,10,11]` ?

Comment: `   while True:n.append(n)` This line will never break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding redundant computations:

```
def fibonacci(indices):
    fibs = {}
    set_of_indices = set(indices)
    f0 = fibs[0] = 0
    f1 = fibs[1] = 1
    for i in range(2,max(indices)+1):
        f2 = f0+f1
        if i in set_of_indices:
            fibs[i] = f2
        f0,f1=f1,f2
    return [fibs[i] for i in indices]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your code a bit and get:

```
def fibonacci(lst):
    def getTerm(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        elif n == 1:
            return 1
        return getTerm(n - 1) + getTerm(n-2)
    return [getTerm(x) for x in lst]
```

Gives output:

```
>>> fibonacci([0,1,2,3])
[0, 1, 1, 2]
>>> fibonacci([5,10,11])
[5, 55, 89]
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not think about creating a function inside a function. Will have that in mind for future reference. Appreciated.

Comment: Why does `getTerm` need to be defined inside of `fibonacci`?